# why dependency analyzer in Intellij does not show me all the dependencies?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

i cloned a project from github in Intellij Idea,
and i want to understand why i can't see all the dependencies in the dependency analyzer.

This a part of the dependencies of my project :
[image]

and, now i launch the Dependency analyzer from the maven windows tool.
[image]

My question is :
why the analyzer does not show me all the dependencies ?
For example, it doesn't show all the com.amazonaws jar.

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Is it possible to share project example for investigation?

Comment: yes of course. you can clone this github repo : https://github.com/rieckpil/blog-tutorials and then open this maven project in this folder : spring-boot-aws-integration-tests

Comment: Did you expand all rows?  AWS libs are likely pulled transitively from the first one "spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging".

Comment: yes it works now. it was a scope focus, which filtered some libraries.